# python function return error on 2.7.8 version

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, return

I'm a beginner to python and I've learned some stuff form youtube tutorials.I have got a kind of nonsense error while defining a function. I think it is because of indention but I don't know why.
you can see a simple function in the first format python doesn't understand what i mean

```
>>> def ef():
    return 6
ef()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> def ef():
        return 9
>>>
>>> ef()
9
>>>
```

and I face this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    ef()
NameError: name 'ef' is not defined.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

When working in the interactive prompt, you have to have an empty line after a function definition. If the line you're typing on doesn't start with ">>>", the interpreter thinks it's a continuation of the function block. Press enter one more time before trying to call `ef()`.